# EncloseJs Nodejs project compiling errors

Tags: node.js

I am compiling complete nodejs project into single executable file in windows using enclosejs.It gives following warnings. Kindly find solution for it.

> \node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js

```
  warning  Cannot resolve 'require(driver + '/connection')'
```

Use a string literal as argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option

> \node_modules\hapi\node_modules\vision\lib\manager.js

```
  warning  Cannot resolve 'require(file)'
```

Use a string literal as argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already included as part of the question.

> Use a string literal as argument for 'require', or leave it as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.

Please refer https://github.com/igorklopov/enclose/wiki/02.Packaging